# How can I italicize one word of a single line y-axis label in RStudio?

Tags: r, yaxis, italics

I'm trying to make my y-axis label read as "*Nam* expression" but seem to be having trouble. I'm using this command (I've tried a number of combinations of quotations and parentheses already but nothing seems to work):

```
plot(NAM_expression_over_time[,2], xlab = "Time (hours)" , ylab =  expression(italic("Nam ")), "expression")
```

I get this error message:

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :    'x' and 'y' lengths
>   differ

How can I go about solving this problem?

Comment: I've also tried this: plot(NAM_expression_over_time[,2], xlab = "Time (hours)" , ylab =  expression(italic("Nam "), + "expression")) and the word Nam (italicized) shows up but not the word "expression"

Comment: I think you want `plot(NAM_expression_over_time[,2], xlab = "Time (hours)" , ylab =  expression(italic("Nam ")~"expression"))`

Comment: MrFlick, Thank you! I was just about to comment that I used plot(NAM_expression_over_time, type = "l", las = 1, xlab = "Time (hours)" , ylab = expression("SLR of" ~italic("Nam"))) (I changed the title) and it worked!